# Creating custom configurations for log4net app.config

Tags: c#, log4net, app-config, log4net-configuration

I extended the log4net library to create my own custom logging. I have a few apps that I want to apply it too. However, I want to add my own custom tags using the log4net app.config settings.

Example Below:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="LogAppender"
          type="LogServiceLib.LogAppender, LogServiceLib">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <ConversionPattern value="%m"  />
  </layout>
  <schema value="TEST" /> 
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"  />
  <appender-ref ref="LogAppender"  />
</root>
</log4net>
```

I added "schema value = "Test" to this, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to access this in code. My hunch is that it is somewhere in the log4netConfigurationSectionHandler, but I am unable to get it.
Is there a way to retrieve the XMLConfig data from within log4net?

NOTE: I am avoiding the use of System.ConfigurationManager for this.

Comment: Log4Net actually has good examples on how to do this on their site.. have you consulted the support site ?

Comment: I haven't found anything simple on there site related to extension libraries on there site, only how to configure the original log4net library. I'm extending theres, and using multiple log sources. it works well, I just want to add parameters using there system instead of using system.configurationManager.

Comment: You would add a public property to `LogServiceLib.LogAppender` called `Schema` to receive the value

Comment: Hehe, i hate it when its something simple and I just can't get it to work. :) Thanks, it worked. I had public schema; in my class, but i needed to add the getter, and setter for it to work. public schema { get; set; }